# Display Raw HTML on the Web Page

Tags: angular

How do I display un-rendered HTML on the web page without escaping everything?

I need to display the HTML of an email template on a page, for someone to copy/paste it to an email program. I tried to put it into a textarea utilizing [innerHtml], bypassing the DomSanitizer with a pipe, which almost worked, except that something (either Angular or the textarea) got rid of some HTML codes. For example, it got rid of the HTML character code #160 (unsure if I can put the ampersand in my question)..

Most of the questions on SO are about rendering the HTML, but I'm struggling to show the HTML code itself, so that the person can copy/paste it.

The only other idea I had was maybe to post the HTML code to a temporary database/location then read it back with a different MIME type.

Thank you,
Dan Chase

Comment: Did you try innerText instead of innerHTML?

Comment: @letsc PERFECT!! Thank you!!!

Comment: Posted the same as answer, if it can help others too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`innerHTML` parses the content and tries to generate an HTML that can be rendered. `innerHTML` is generally used when you want to insert new elements in your DOM using Javascript. If you want to simply render your content as text, you should use `innerText`.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what purpose this serves but couldn’t you just take the HTML, paste it into a new file within a text editor like atom or sublime so you can preserve the formatting, then save it and email the file or share it via a cloud storage provider?

Comment: The HTML is being generated by the program, the real trick was making it so they could copy/paste. I tried emailing it as an attachment, but they said if Email was down they would not be able to use the program. letsc answered above, turns out I was just using the wrong tag, but your comment made me think of an alternative of maybe pushing the file to a storage provider, or somewhere else and then just showing the link to download it.